# VHDL/Verilog - Does a math operation in a range statement get snythesized?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, system-verilog

Say you have the following code,

```
signal a : std_logic_vector( N - 1 downto 0 );
```

Or,

```
for i in 0 to N - 1
    ...
```

Does the `N-1` part get synthesized into actual logic, or does the FPGA software (e.g. Quartus) do the math before creating the logic?

Example use case, say generic `N` represents the number of desired bits. Is it better to have a generic `Nm1` which holds the subtraction, or can I get by using `N-1` as above without it creating additional logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `N` is a generic parameter, it is considered as a constant at synthesis time. Your logic synthesizer, as all logic synthesizers I know, will propagate constants before inferring any piece of hardware. The synthesizer will compute the `N-1` expression before synthesis and this operation will not cost you any single transistor. It would be the same with a much more complex operation on constants like, for instance, calling a function. Example:

```
function log2_up(x: positive) return natural is
begin
    if x = 1 then 
        return 0;
    else
        return log2_up((x+1)/2) + 1;
    end if;
end function log2_up;
...
constant word_width: positive := 64;
constant write_byte_enable_width: positive := log2_up(64 / 8);
```

is synthesizable by all logic synthesizers I know and computing `write_byte_enable_width` does not cost a single transistor; it is computed beforehand by the synthesizer during the constant propagation phase.

Answer (score 1):

In both of these cases, the value of N would have to be calculated at compile time. It isn't -- and cannot be! -- generated in logic.

Keep in mind that any HDL code ultimately has to be able to synthesize to physical hardware. Changing the number of bits in a signal, or changing the number of times some logic is instantiated, isn't something that can be done electronically.

Comment: To clarify, if I were to go to an RTL view I should not see that additional adders were employed in the design to do the `N - 1` calculation?

Comment: N has to be a constant value at compile time (like @duskwuff already said). _N-1_ is calculated by your synthesis tool! **The FPGA won't calculate this value in any adder!** It's only a description (in the case of a logic_vector) how many hardware components are needed for your FPGA to build this circuit design.

Comment: Note: "any HDL code ultimately has to be able to synthesize to physical hardware" is not true. HDL code (both VHDL and (System)Verilog) is used for writing testbenches and behavioral models too. In that case you can do everything that other programming languages allow you to do, like dynamically allocating memory.